# {{ form_widget(form.fieldsName) }} raw rendering

Tags: symfony, twig

First of all i have already searched and tried a lot of methods here but with no success.
My problem is that i have a field in my database that contains `<br/>` 
that get displayed on twig `{{form_widget(form.fieldsName)}}`
I do not want them to be displayed and do there job which is break line.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{form_widget(form.fieldsName| raw) }}
```

`raw` will escape html characters

Comment: i have already tried it :/, here is my code `{{ form_widget(form.lieuTravail, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder':'user.profil.placeholder.adresse_bureau'|trans({}, 'AppBundle')}}) }}` (i have added this line to the config file `autoescape: false`  it works with all type of fields except the ones of the form)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `<br />` in form elements, you should create your own form templates. Read the docs on https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

For using `<br />`in the content of any form field, symfony/twig is doing the right thing. But using `{{form_widget(form.fieldsName| raw) }}` have no sense, because `form_widget` is a rendering function for twig to output real, unescaped html.

Comment: okey thank you, but the above answer is also working. so i will leave it like that for others to have 2 choices